# Tridion Content Manager Batch Processor Not Working!

Tags: sdl-tridion

Recently, when we were trying to publish multiple items, it was directly showing us status Success in Publishing Queue. When we opened the transactions, it was not passing through the usual stages of Publishing(Waiting For Publish, Transporting, Deployment, Committing Deployment, etc). And the changes we made were also not getting reflected to the frontend.

When we tried to publish items one by one, it was passing through each stage and our changes were also able to reflect on the FrontEnd.

I went to the CME and saw that all the services were showing running status. I restarted the Tridion Content Manager Batch Processor and things started working fine as expected and each of the items in the publishing queue was passing through the different stages of publishing.

Since the Batch Processor was showing a status of Error in cloudwatch during that hour of the incident even when its status was showing as running in the CME server, I am unable to find the root cause for its malfunctioning.

Any idea why this might have happened?

Comment: Check the Windows Event Logs (in particular the Tridion Event Log) on the server(s) which run the Batch Processor Service.

Comment: Hi @RickPannekoek , I checked the event logs and it showed me the error with some tcm id of component saying that it does not exist. Even though it does.

The issue re occured for a different component after some days. Also we found the below error :

Comment: <Provider Name="Tridion Batching" /> 
 <Data>A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_ITEMS_DELETE_82". Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. The wait operation timed out Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Batching Errorcode: 0 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ISessionAwareCoreService.Delete(String id) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at ction, ParallelLoopState loopState)</Data> 
  </EventData>

Comment: Please update the question with a (formatted) event message rather than attaching it as a  comment (it's very hard to read as a comment).

Comment: Despite it being hard to read, I see a database timeout when trying to Delete an item. I guess that is unrelated to your publishing Batch, but please ensure that the database statistics are up-to-date.